# Python datetime split in hours for API URL in range

Tags: python, datetime

I need to split a day into 4 times something like this into 2 variables so that I can pass them dynamically to the API Calls and process it.

This almost works but

```
2020-06-08 00:00:00 2020-06-08 05:59:59
2020-06-08 06:00:00 2020-06-08 11:59:59
2020-06-08 12:00:00 2020-06-08 17:59:59
2020-06-08 18:00:00 2020-06-08 23:59:59
```

This almost works but when trying to assign gives me an error not sure where I am doing wrong or missing something in datetime to string conversion

```
import datetime
mydate=['2020-06-08 00:00:00', '2020-06-08 23:59:59']
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
hour = datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
start_time,  end_time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, fmt) for d in mydate]
now = start_time
while now <= end_time:
...  print now.strftime(fmt)
...  now += hour
...  print now-timedelta(seconds=1)
```

if i replace the print in the while loop to assignment like this

```
 while now <= end_time:
...    from=now.strftime(fmt)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    from=now.strftime(fmt)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

immediately throws an error in the python shell, using python 2.7 and don't want to use any other external packages (ex. don't want with pandas or others )

Comment: ``from`` is a reserved keyword you cant use that as variable names.

Comment: from is a keyword in python like `from collections import OrderedDict` so you cant use `from` as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks, forget that I shouldn't use the **form**, was just lost in solving, and using the same name as in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> mydate=['2020-06-08 00:00:00', '2020-06-08 23:59:59']
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>> hour = timedelta(hours=6)
>>> start_time,  end_time = [datetime.strptime(d, fmt) for d in mydate]
>>> now = start_time
>>> while now <= end_time:
...   st_from=now.strftime(fmt)
...   now += hour
...   st_end=now-timedelta(seconds=1)
...   print st_from,st_end
```

2020-06-08 00:00:00 2020-06-08 05:59:59
2020-06-08 06:00:00 2020-06-08 11:59:59
2020-06-08 12:00:00 2020-06-08 17:59:59
2020-06-08 18:00:00 2020-06-08 23:59:59

Thanks for pointing and giving a hint of the reserved word.